# undefined method `scoped' for Forum:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been working on a simple forum based on [forum monster demo](https://github.com/gitt/forum_monster_demo). I am currently trying to update the application from rails 3.0.9 to 3.2.11. When I load the application I get a undefined method `scoped' for Forum:Module

```
Extracted source (around line #13):
10:         <%= link_to "Delete Category", category_path(category), :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this category?", :method => :delete if can? :manage, category %>
11:       </span>
12:     </div>
13:     <% if category.forums.size > 0 %>
14:     <div>
15:       <table>
16:         <tr class="smaller">
```

Here is my Forum modle

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :posts, :through => :topics

  belongs_to :category

  # Accessors
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :state, :position, :category_id

  # Scopes
  default_scope :order => :'position ASC'

  # Validations
  validates :title,       :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :category_id, :presence => true
end
```

Here is what I learned from poking around in the console

```
ricky ~/forum $ rails console   
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0> Category.all.size
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` ORDER BY position ASC
=> 2
irb(main):002:0> Category.all.each do |cat|
irb(main):003:1* puts cat.forums.size
irb(main):004:1> end
  Category Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` ORDER BY position ASC
NoMethodError: undefined method `scoped' for Forum:Module
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:123:in `target_scope'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:87:in `scoped'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:41:in `count_records'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:261:in `size'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `size'
    from (irb):3:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):2:in `each'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0> puts Forum.all.size
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for Forum:Module
    from (irb):5
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0>
```

Thanks in advance for any incite about the nature of this issue.

Comment: some of scope things are deprecated in Rails 3.1 itself checkout [this](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Forum' model class is named exactly the same as module in your config/application.rb

Rename your model or application.

Comment: That was it thank you! I really new to ruby & rails and didn't realise I couldn't name the application the same as a model.