# undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am really new to rails, and I have a simple forum app based off forum monster. I am currently working on updating it from rails 3.0.9 to 3.2.11. After fixing this self inflicted [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393641/undefined-method-scoped-for-forummodule/14403475), I ran into an other issue.

It would seem that when I try to display a topic the user (from post.user) object is nil when it should not be.

Here is the error

```
Extracted source (around line #17):
14:       <% @topic.posts.each do |post| %>
15:       <tr>
16:         <td class="post_author" rowspan="2">
17:           <span class="name"><%= post.user.username %></span>
18:           <span class="avatar"><%= image_tag post.user.gravatar_url %></span>
19:           <span class="info smaller">
20:             <p><strong><%= "Administrator" if post.user.admin? %></strong></p>
```

Here is my view app/views/topics/show.html.erb

```
<div class="right controls"><%= link_to "Back to Forum", forum_path(@topic.forum) %></div>
<div class="module">
  <div class="module_header">
    <%= @topic.title %>
    <span class="right controls">
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_path(@topic) if can? :manage, @topic %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", @topic, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete if can? :manage, @topic %>
      <%= link_to @topic.sticky ? "Unstick" : "Sticky", {:controller => 'topics', :action => 'update', :topic => {:sticky => @topic.sticky ? "false" : "true" }}, :method => :put if can? :moderate, @topic %>
      <%= link_to @topic.locked ? "Unlock" : "Lock", {:controller => 'topics', :action => 'update', :topic => {:locked => @topic.locked ? "false" : "true" }}, :method => :put if can? :moderate, @topic %>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <% @topic.posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="post_author" rowspan="2">
          <span class="name"><%= post.user.username %></span>
          <span class="avatar"><%= image_tag post.user.gravatar_url %></span>
          <span class="info smaller">
            <p><strong><%= "Administrator" if post.user.admin? %></strong></p>
            Posts <%= post.user.posts.size %><br />
            Registered <%=l post.user.created_at %><br />
          </span>
        </td>
        <td class="post_header">
          <span class="left post_date smaller">Posted <%=l post.created_at %></span>
          <span class="right controls">
            <%= link_to "Reply", new_topic_post_path(@topic) if can? :create, @topic.posts.new %>
            <%= link_to "Quote", new_topic_post_path(@topic, :quote => post) if can? :create, @topic.posts.new %>
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) if can? :update, post %>
            <%= link_to "Delete", post, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete if can? :destroy, post %>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="post_body">
          <%= post.body.bbcode_to_html().html_safe %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right controls"><p><%= link_to "Back to Forum", forum_path(@topic.forum) %></p></div>
```

here is the controller app/controlers/topics_controller.rb

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :forum
  load_and_authorize_resource :topic, :through => :forum, :shallow => true

  def show
    @topic.hit! if @topic
  end

  def create
    @topic.user ||= current_user

    if @topic.save
      flash[:notice] = "Topic was successfully created."
      redirect_to topic_url(@topic)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @topic.update_attributes(params[:topic])
      flash[:notice] = "Topic was updated successfully."
      redirect_to topic_url(@topic)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @topic.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Topic was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to forum_url(@topic.forum)
    end
  end

end
```

Rails console output confirms that the code in the view should work, and that the post does have a user.

```
ricky ~/forum $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0> Topic.find(1).posts.each do |p|
irb(main):002:1* puts p.user.username
irb(main):003:1> end
  Topic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `topics`.* FROM `topics` WHERE `topics`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY sticky DESC, updated_at DESC LIMIT 1
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`topic_id` = 1 ORDER BY created_at ASC
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
admin
=> [#<Post id: 1, body: "Forum Monster is a simple forum generator written i...", forum_id: 1, topic_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-19 06:57:23", updated_at: "2013-01-19 06:57:23">]
irb(main):004:0>
```

I think I might have to add an ability for cancan can :read User, but I am not really sure.

thanks in advance for helping this confused android developer 0.o

**EDIT**

view complete source [HERE](http://rickbarrette.org/cgit/forum.git/tree/?h=rails3.2)

As you can see below that the post model does indeed validate the presence of the user

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  belongs_to :forum, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :topic, :counter_cache => true, :touch => true 
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :counter_cache => true

  # Accessors
  attr_accessible :body

  # Validations
  validates :body, :presence => true
  validates :user, :presence => true

  # Default Scope
  default_scope :order => 'created_at ASC'

  # Scope to display only the last n posts. Used for "Recent Posts" display
  scope :recent, lambda {
    |c| reorder('created_at desc').limit(c)
  }

  # Callbacks
  before_save :topic_locked?

  # Methods
  private
    def topic_locked?
      if topic.locked?
        errors.add(:base, "That topic is locked")
        false
      end
    end
end
```

What is getting me that there is only 1 post that exists in the database that was seeded, and it was created via

```
@current_user = User.find_by_username("admin")
@current_user.topics.create!(...)
```

Comment: What is the full error? If you look up the post that's causing the error in the console, does it have a user?

Comment: Yes, when I look up the post in the console the post does have a user.

Answer (score 3):

replace with:

```
<%= post.user.username unless post.user.blank? %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand why this fixed the problem, as there is only one post in the database; but I have found a solution.

```
<% @topic.posts.each do |post| %>
  <% if !post.user.blank? %>
    ...display post here...
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, the collection `@topic.posts` contains at least one post without a user, and the rest of the code in your view do not anticipate that.

- Probably your application should not allow to create a Post without a user, you should add a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence) to check that the user is present when the post is saved, and prevent the creation of post without user.

  ```
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  ```
- If your application should allow a Post without user, add a `if post.user.present?` in your view:

  ```
  <% @topic.posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="post_author" rowspan="2">
        <% if post.user.present? %>
          <span class="name"><%= post.user.username %></span>
          <span class="avatar"><%= image_tag post.user.gravatar_url %></span>
          <span class="info smaller">
            <p><strong><%= "Administrator" if post.user.admin? %></strong></p>
            Posts <%= post.user.posts.size %><br />
            Registered <%=l post.user.created_at %><br />
          </span>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do depending on whether you want the post user to be blank ever or not blank at all.

**1) If the post user can be blank:**

Check if the post user is present, this way you will not get the 'nil' user.

'@userpost = post.user.blank? " ": post.user.username'

**2) If the post user cannot be blank:**

In this case, you could impose the association like in post model, 'belongs_to :user' and in user model, 'has_many :posts' and a constraint like 'validates_presence_of :post'.